# Ruby segmentation fault on rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

This is really odd. I was doing fine in this Rails 3.2.11 app, having run rspec earlier this a.m. I created a new branch, changed a file, committed, and ran rspec spec/ when I got a slew of Segmentation errors and a stack trace about as long as I've seen it.

I've updated rvm and tried to install earlier versions of ruby 1.9.3. I kept getting hangs on pristine gem sets and bailed by restarting. After restart of OS X 10.8.3 I was able to install ruby 1.9.3-p429 cleanly. But rspec still bails. The full stack trace is https://gist.github.com/sam452/5808849. I've bundle install'd the gems since they were cleaned out. I've also attempted to run the rspec generator again but it seemed to only overwrite one support file. Rails, rake, cucumber seem to run OK. Rake fails when it gets to the rspec command.

I've attempted to pull what appears to be relevant portions from the stacktrace:

```
    Happenstance:tickat sam$ rspec spec/
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/core_ext/exception.rb:9: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
```

#### Control frame information

```
c:0064 p:---- s:0204 b:0204 l:000203 d:000203 CFUNC  :callers
c:0063 p:0064 s:0201 b:0201 l:000290 d:0026c0 LAMBDA /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/better_errors-0.8.0/lib/better_errors/core_ext/exception.rb:9
c:0062 p:---- s:0198 b:0198 l:000197 d:000197 FINISH
```

#### Ruby level backtrace information

```
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
/Users/sam/apps/tickat/spec/controllers/admin/events_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

#### C level backtrace information

```
   See Crash Report log file under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter or
   /Library/Logs/CrashReporter, for the more detail of.
```

#### Other runtime information

```
* Loaded script: /Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/bin/rspec
* Loaded features:
    0 enumerator.so
    1 /Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.3.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
```

All the way down to line 2030.

Comment: What happens when you revert the change you made? What was the change you made?

Comment: The change was to a font name in a css file. Everything closed up. What's curious is when I revert back to commit from this a.m. Rspec works. Must be because in 'detached HEAD' state. When I checkout master, it goes back to the ruby fault.

Comment: So when you change the font name back, it works properly?

Comment: No. Rspec only runs when I'm in the 'detached HEAD' state. In reading up on this state, I'm not seeing a clue why this is. From what I read, it's just not pointing to a specific reference, but the files are essentially the same ones from the commit I checked out? Git reset or commit and rspec fails again. If so, reverting to earlier commit should run, but it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to remove `better_errors` and possibly `binding_of_caller` from the test group in your Gemfile, this is what's causing the error. If you look at the line that reports the Segmentation Faul, it is `better_errors` that's reporting it:

```
.../better_errors/core_ext/exception.rb:9: [BUG] Segmentation fault
```

So your Gemfile should look something like this:

```
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

# for testing to work with rspec
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'ffaker'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

Answer (score 19):

**Rspec** causes in some cases a segmentation fault, for example if you define a variable with `let!` recursively. This can produce a `vm_call_cfunc - cfp consistency error` in the RSpec core, a Ruby Crash Report and a `Segmentation fault: 11`

```
let!(:some_var) { "Some value" }

describe '.method' do
  ...
  let!(:some_var) { create(:model, some_var: some_var) }
end
```

Comment: Another case I just ran into was accidentally stubbing an object inside it's own `let` block. e.g. `let(:obj) { create :obj; allow(obj).to receive(:thing) }`. It's an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks... it was a silly recursion that happened in my case.

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't know why rspec works in 'detached HEAD' state, but not while in a commit, I ended up gem uninstall better_errors which I hate doing. In the first few lines of the stacktrace it appears that for some reason there is a conflict with Ruby and better_errors. I will submit a report. Thanks for helping.